# Keep the QLineEdit's Placeholder even if the user types

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, placeholder

How can I keep my QLineEdit's placeholder shown even if the user types?

To extend this, I am creating a text box. I want to add an autocomplete feature to the input box. Now, the question is how to do that? One way thought is to display the autocomplete text as a placeholder and listen for the right arrow button and then fill in the text. However, it looks like the placeholder gets hidden once the user starts typing :(.

Tried: Create a QLabel and add the autocomplete text. Stack the label under the input box and set the input box background to transparent. Issue: My Text Box is inside of a label. When I am trying to create a QLabel with the parent as the QLineEdit, and then stacking it under the input box.

Comment: If you want autocompletion, use [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! I would read and get back :D